# How to automatically run cocoa application after install via installer

Tags: macos, cocoa

I have a built a cocoa application that I have packaged using package maker so that the app is installed using the installer.

After install is finished I want to run the installed application. In the package maker I can see postinstall actions, but I don't find an appropriate action to execute the application.

Any ideas what should I do ? my app is install in the /Applications/my.app

Should I write a script file of some sort or should the package maker help me run the app?

Thanks,
Ahmed

Answer (score 2):

You need to add a `postflight` (assuming you want this for both installs and upgrades. If you just want it for installs, use `postinstall`).

Just call `open "$3/Applications/my.app"` to launch.

`$3` is the install target. It's usually going to be `/`, but if you're being installed onto another volume, it could be something different like `/Volumes/Other_Drive`.

Comment: How to set postflight script in pakagemaker? I have only options for [preinstall and postinstall](https://www.dropbox.com/s/4rjnge1gqzcg5wk/Screen%20shot%202013-10-21%20at%203.22.04%20PM.png).

Comment: You may have an older version of PackageMaker. 3.0.6 should show 6 scripts here (Pre/Postinstall, Pre/Postflight, Pre/Postupgrade). You can get the latest PackageMaker from developer.apple.com/downloads (Auxiliary Tools for Xcode). Note, however, that Apple is not continuing to support PackageMaker. They really, really want you to switch to pkgbuild and productbuild. If you don't *have* to use PackageMaker (to include installer plugins for instance), you should switch. pkgbuild does not have a GUI (but the PackageMaker GUI has always been confusing anyway).